# how can I draw a foot prints using canvas with path?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I saw the accurate answer here [Animated footsteps in html svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653467/animated-footsteps-in-html-svg?newreg=35a1ff59566047d7a6d9afbebbd4401d)

It is working at it is however when I use dynamic path value (in percentage), It doesn't work. Please help me.

This is my sample canvas. I want to put the foot steps on top of it.

```js
function drawImageCanvas() {
  var canvas  = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var base_image = new Image();

  base_image.width =  400;
  base_image.height = 400;
  base_image.onload = function(){    
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 400, 400);

  }
  base_image.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567459169668-95d355371bda?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80';
    }

drawImageCanvas();
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "not working". Also, it would be helpful if you included the portion of the code that you have modified and what did you expect to happen.

Comment: I just change the variable path with dynamic value(it is actually in percentage) so It seems that the path positioning is not right and also change this at the beginning
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

my canvas has already an image as a background so i am trying to put the foot steps on top of it.